# Bash Shell - The : Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The colon command is a null command.

The : construct is also useful in the conditional setting of variables. For example,

```
: ${var:=value}
```

Without the **:**, the shell would try to evaluate $var as a command. <=???

I don't quite understand the last sentence in above statement. Can anyone give me some details?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var=badcommand
$var
```

you will get

```
bash: badcommand: command not found
```

Try

```
var=
${var:=badcommand}
```

and you will get the same.

The shell (e.g. bash) always tries to run the first word on each command line as a command, even after doing variable expansion.

The only exception to this is

```
var=value
```

which the shell treats specially.

The trick in the example you provide is that `${var:=value}` works anywhere on a command line, e.g.

```
# set newvar to somevalue if it isn't already set
echo ${newvar:=somevalue}
# show that newvar has been set by the above command
echo $newvar
```

But we don't really even want to echo the value, so we want something better than
`echo ${newvar:=somevalue}`.

The `:` command lets us do the assignment without any other action.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what the man page writers meant was

```
: ${var:=value}
```

Can be used as a short cut instead of say

```
if [ -z "$var" ]; then
    var=value
fi
```

Comment: -z string True if the string is null (an empty string)

Answer (score 1):

`${var}` on its own executes the command stored in `$var`. Adding substitution parameters does not change this, so you use `:` to neutralize this.

Comment: too true. I doubt this really explained it to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ help :
:: :
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

Comment: Does anybody else think that this is in itself a slight paradox ? `No effect`/`Exit status: always succeeds`. This implies that of course it _does_ do stuff, just no explicitely. It does variable expansion, assignment, and clobbers the exit code.

Comment: Yep, does "almost" nothing ;-)